# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property gameAdapter has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently working my college assignment. I've already stuck in this problem for awhile, can somebody point out my mistakes. Much appreciated! I created a class that return a list of game, when I trying to populate my recycle view data. This error is shown:

> 2020-01-09 13:27:58.937 20456-20456/com.example.android.navigation
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.android.navigation, PID: 20456
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigation/com.example.android.navigation.MainActivity}:
>   kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   gameAdapter has not been initialized

```
class TitleFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var gameAdapter: GameRecyclerAdapter

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    val mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_game_list) as RecyclerView
    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager)

    val data = DataSource.createDataSet()
    gameAdapter.submitList(data)

    return view
   }


 }

package com.example.android.navigation.models



class DataSource {

companion object{

    fun createDataSet(): ArrayList<GameList>{
        var list = ArrayList<GameList>()
        list.add(
                GameList(
                        title = "Testing1",
                        body = "dummy data of testing1",
                        username = "alex"
                )
        )
        list.add(
                GameList(
                        title = "Testing2",
                        body = "dummy data of testing1",
                        username = "chris"
                )
        )
        list.add(
                GameList(
                        title = "Testing3",
                        body = "dummy data of testing1",
                        username = "wong"
                )
        )
        list.add(
                GameList(
                        title = "Testing4",
                        body = "dummy data of testing1",
                        username = "long"
                )
        )
        list.add(
                GameList(
                        title = "Testing5",
                        body = "dummy data of testing1",
                        username = "james"
                )
        )
        return list
    }

   }

}
```

Comment: you never create an instance of `gameAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `GameRecyclerAdapter` instance and assign  to `gameAdapter`.

Add this line in `onCreateView` method before you call this method `gameAdapter.submitList(data)`.

```
   gameAdapter=GameRecyclerAdapter()
```